# Text alignment in beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I make a presentation using LaTeX. But I have a slide with picture and text and I want a text to be aligned to the right. How to do this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{Подпрограма Solver}
\end{block}

\begin{itemize}
\item Изпълнява се n -- пъти; \\ 
\item $\overline{F}(\varphi) = -\varphi \, '' + \sin \varphi - \gamma$; \\
  \item $\varepsilon$ -- стоп--критерий. \\
\end{itemize}

\tikzstyle{my loop}=[->,to path={
.. controls +(300:1) and +(560:1) .. (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}]


\begin{tikzpicture}

\path (0, 0) node(a) [ellipse, draw] {$\varphi_0$};
\path (0, -1) node(b) [rectangle, draw] {$\varphi^n = \varphi^{n-1} + \tau_n \cdot     w^n$};
\path (0, -3) node(c) [diamond, draw] {$\| \overline{F}(\varphi^n) \| < \varepsilon$};
\path (6, -3) node(d) [rectangle, draw] {Продължаваме (получили сме решение)};

\draw[->] (a) to (b);
\draw[->] (b) to (c);
\draw[->] (c) to node[above] {да} (d);
\draw[->] (c) to (0, -5) node[right] {не} to (-2.5, -5) to (-2.5, 0) to (a);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have attempted to fix your character encoding problem, but I do not read any language written with Cyrillic, so I can't tell if I did it right.

Comment: Also, please tell us which text should be right-aligned and currently isn't.

Comment: I want the text in itemize area to be right-aligned.

Comment: @Владислав Найденов: Only the text or also the bullets?

Comment: Do you want the whole itemize to be placed at the right part of the frame? So you could simply pack it into a minipage with 0.5\textwidth or similar and than place a `\hfill` before.

Comment: Yes, I want the whole itemize to be placed at the right part of the frame. How to pack it into a minipage?.

Answer (score 14):

You can try `\hfill`.

```
\hfill Right aligned text
```

should do what you want.

Comment: I already try this but it didn't work.

Comment: instead of `\\` use `\linebreak` and then `\hfill` should work.

Comment: Doesn't work either for me @barbarabeeton

Comment: @AccidentalBismuthTransform -- To force the `\hfill` to not be lost, an extreme approach is `\linebreak\null\fill`.

Answer (score 7):

For this purpose, the best thing to do is to use the `columns` environment.

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{my loop}=[->,to path={
 .. controls +(300:1) and +(560:1) .. (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}]
\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{Подпрограма Solver}
\end{block}

\begin{columns}[T]

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
% first column: the image
\begin{tikzpicture}     
\path (0, 0) node(a) [ellipse, draw] {$\varphi_0$};
\path (0, -1) node(b) [rectangle, draw] {$\varphi^n = \varphi^{n-1} + \tau_n \cdot w^n$};
\path (0, -3) node(c) [diamond, draw] {$\| \overline{F}(\varphi^n) \| < \varepsilon$};
\path (6, -3) node(d) [rectangle, draw] {Continue (we received an answer)};

\draw[->] (a) to (b);
\draw[->] (b) to (c);
\draw[->] (c) to node[above] {if yes} (d);
\draw[->] (c) to (0, -5) node[right] {if not} to (-2.5, -5) to (-2.5, 0) to (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
% second column: the text
\begin{itemize}
\item Runs n - times; \\ 
\item $\overline{F}(\varphi) = -\varphi \, '' + \sin \varphi - \gamma$; \\
\item $\varepsilon$ -- stop-test. \\
\end{itemize}
\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Actually I translated in english the labels: sorry if it is not precise.

The graphical result is:

[image]